# How to plot frequency of one event with respect to other?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, matplotlib

I want to use python/matplotlib/pandas for my purpose.

Problem description: I have an excel sheet (which I can read as a pandas dataframe) containing a table of true and estimated values. I want to somehow capture this information over a plot of actual (horizontal axis) vs estimated values (vertical axis). The excel sheet looks somewhat as follows:

[image]

I am thinking of a scatter plot. But I don't know how to obtain such a plot. In this case it is not a simple scatter plot. Also, the axes need to be handled differently. If there is some other appropriate way, please feel free to suggest.

**Edit 1:**

As suggested by @BrenBarn, I posted my query in [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221863/how-to-visualize-classifier-output). One answer which I particularly liked shows the following visualization:
[(see link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCpCZ.png)

I want to generate a similar scatter plot using python. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: If you are asking about how to *decide* what the visualization should look like, that is not really on topic for this site.  This site would be for asking how to implement a particular visualization once you've decided what you want it to look like.  You might try [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) instead.  That said, one possibility is to plot a visual representation of the "confusion matrix", a grid with categories in rows and columns and each cell shaded according to how many times a certain true category was classified as a certain estimated category.

Comment: @BrenBarn: Thanks a lot for suggesting 'Cross Validated'.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make that table into a plot similar to the one you link to, I would first make an array with values with one axis corresponding to "actual value" and the other to "estimated value" (thus including all the zero values that are not in your table above):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
label = ['A', 'F', 'J', 'P', 'T', 'Z']
nlabel = 6
values = np.zeros([nlabel, nlabel])
values[0, 0] = 10; values[0, 2] = 10; values[0, 3] = 10
values[1, 1] = 40; values[2, 1] = 10; values[3, 3] = 10
values[3, 4] = 10; values[4, 5] = 30; values[4, 3] = 20
values[5, 4] = 10
print "  ", label
for i in np.arange(nlabel): print label[i], values[i]
```

Printing that just to make sure that it looks like your table above:

```
   ['A', 'F', 'J', 'P', 'T', 'Z']
A [ 10.   0.  10.  10.   0.   0.]
F [  0.  40.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
J [  0.  10.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
P [  0.   0.   0.  10.  10.   0.]
T [  0.   0.   0.  20.   0.  30.]
Z [  0.   0.   0.   0.  10.   0.]
```

Then I would use those values to scale the size of the markers in matplotlib.pyplot.scatter as below.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in np.arange(nlabel):
  plt.scatter(np.arange(nlabel), i * np.ones_like(values[i]), 
              s=values[i] * 42, marker='s')

plt.axes([0, nlabel+1, 0, nlabel+1])
ticklabel = [item.get_text() for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]
ticklabel[1:1+nlabel] = label
ax.set_xticklabels(ticklabel)
ax.set_yticklabels(ticklabel)
ax.set_xlabel('Estimated')
ax.set_ylabel('Actual')
plt.show()
```

That should give you a plot fairly similar to the one you linked to. I didn't do the trend line or the numbers inside the squares, but Google/StackOverflow should be able to provide you with the solution to those.